# TableView Unit Test on Asynchronous Service call

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am writing unit test cases for my app having UITableView with data coming from the server. I have added test cases for my TableView except `numberOfRowsInSection`.

I am following below link for UITableView test cases: 
[Xcode 5 test UITableview with XCTest Framework](http://blog.typpz.com/2014/04/27/xcode-5-test-uitableview-with-xctest-framework/)

Can anyone suggest how to write a test case for `numberOfRowsInSection`which shows the data coming from an asynchronous service call? 
Any idea or example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) and fake your data with json. Add json file with face data into your project (be careful with selecting proper target). And then use next code to test data:

```
import XCTest
import OHHTTPStubs

class TestSomeRequest: XCTestCase {

    // MARK: - Attributes
    fileprivate let endpoint = "yourendpoint"
    fileprivate let apiUrl = "yoururl"
    fileprivate let path = "yourpath"
}


// MARK: - Setup & Tear Down
extension TestSomeRequest {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        stub(condition: isHost((URL(string: apiUrl)?.host)!) && isPath(path), response: {_ in
            guard let path = OHPathForFile("TestDataJson.json", type(of: self)) else {
                preconditionFailure("Could Not Find Test File!")
            }
            return OHHTTPStubsResponse(fileAtPath: path, statusCode: 200, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"])
        })
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
        OHHTTPStubs.removeAllStubs()
    }
}


// MARK: - Tests
extension TestSomeRequest {
    func testNumberOfRowsInSection() {
        let fetchExpectation = expectation(description: "Test Fetching")
        let viewController = YourViewController()
        YourDataManager.shared.fetchData(for: endpoint, success: {
            XCTAssertEqual(viewController.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), expectedNumberOfRows, "Number Of Rows In Section 0 Should Match!")
            fetchExpectation.fulfill()
        }, failure: nil)
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 60, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to fake data, just use this test method:

```
func testNumberOfRowsInSection() {
    let fetchExpectation = expectation(description: "Test Fetching")
    let viewController = YourViewController()
    YourDataManager.shared.fetchData(for: endpoint, success: {
        XCTAssertEqual(viewController.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), expectedNumberOfRows, "Number Of Rows In Section 0 Should Match!")
        fetchExpectation.fulfill()
    }, failure: nil)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 60, handler: nil)
}
```